# How to use IProject, IFolder, and IFile in a treeview to show only required files?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to display only specific files in my `TreeViewer`. Like files with **.docx** extension only. After lot of research I found that this might me possible by using  `IProject`, `IFolder`, and `IFile`.

How to use  `IProject`, `IFolder`, and `IFile` in a `TreeViewer` to show only required files?

Comment: Im able to display the all the directories and files and subfiles in a system.But im not able to display specific files.that is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a filter using the TreeViewer#addFilter method, where you can filter out the required files.